# Android gridview how to deselect an item which lies outside the current view(currently visible items)

Tags: android, gridview

I have a custom gridView with an item layout consisting of an imageView and a textView with a background. The textView works as a **selector**, since I don't want to use the default one.

This scenario works fine as long as all the items of the gridView fit on the screen. But for the case of a scrollable gridView : if I select an item and then select another after scrolling down, the item selected first does not get deselected since it **wasn't part of the view**.

Here is the selector code used in my MainActivity :

```
final int size = gridView.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    if( i == position && gridView.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
       gridView.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
       gridView.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

I want to know how to make the textView (my selector for the gridView) INVISIBLE when it lies outside the view.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Keep a list of references to each TextView (in an Array, HashSet, or something else), and then iterate through it and make sure each one is deselected before selecting another.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, not sure if I've done it correctly. Could you guide me through it? 
"make sure each one is deselected before selecting another".. Unable to deselect anything outside the view

Comment: ArrayList<TextView> textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>();
TextView a = new TextView(context);
GridLayout.add(a);
textViews.add(a);

and then when you want to select something new:
for(TextView t : textViews){
    t.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
}

and then finally set the view you want to visible.

Comment: This is assuming textviews are the views you want to set visible. Switch textView for whatever object it actually is.

Comment: What do you mean by "GridLayout.add(a)"?

Comment: Thats populating the gridview.

Comment: Another way to do this is when you first set a view visible, save its reference in a variable, say, variable A. Then, when you are selecting something else, deselect A and then set A to the new view and make it visible.